# Curves contained in a plane spanned by its derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Suppose $\boldsymbol{r}(t)$ is a smooth vector-valued function $I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. a curve. For each $t\in I$, $\frac{{\rm d}^k\boldsymbol{r}}{{\rm d}t^k}$ is a linear combination of $\frac{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{r}}{{\rm d}t},\cdots,\frac{{\rm d}^{k-1}\boldsymbol{r}}{{\rm d}t^{k-1}}$ and $\frac{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{r}}{{\rm d}t},\cdots,\frac{{\rm d}^{k-1}\boldsymbol{r}}{{\rm d}t^{k-1}}$ are linearly independent. Then the whole curve is contained in an invariant plane spanned by $\frac{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{r}}{{\rm d}t},\cdots,\frac{{\rm d}^{k-1}\boldsymbol{r}}{{\rm d}t^{k-1}}$.

My book says that it suffices to prove that the derivatives of the basis $\{\frac{{\rm d}\boldsymbol{r}}{{\rm d}t},\cdots,\frac{{\rm d}^{k-1}\boldsymbol{r}}{{\rm d}t^{k-1}}\}$ are linear combinations of the basis itself, which is obviously. But I don't know why it works. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to be careful, it's an affine plane (not necessarily passing through the origin).

Note that the $(k-1)$-plane spanned by the first $k-1$ derivatives is constant as a function of $t$, and for any vector $A$ orthogonal to that plane, we have $A\cdot \big(r(t)-r(t_0)\big)=0$. Can you finish?

Comment: I have difficulty proving the plane is constant… I don't  know how to discribe the plane as a function is constant. Can you give me more hint?

Comment: What is your background? Do you know about wedge products of vectors?

Comment: I just know its definition. Maybe I can read some referrence.

Comment: Let $v_i$ be the $i$th derivative. Either show that the derivative of the multivector $v_1\wedge \dots \wedge v_{k-1}$ is a multiple of the multivector, or argue directly that you can choose the coefficients $c_i$ to make the linear combination $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} c_i(t) v_i(t)$ constant and arbitrary in the span.